# Specific algorithm sorting n elements with m distinct values

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sorting

I am going through exercies for an exam in algorithm analysis and this is one of them:

> Present an algorithm that takes as input a list of n elements (that
>   are comparable) and sorts them in O(n log m) time, where m is the
>   number of distinct values in the input list.

I have read about the common sorting algorithms and I really can't come up with a solution.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's even possible to solve this in `O(n + m)`, have a look at Counting sort.

Comment: Maybe `O(n log m)` is what happens when the elements are only comparable (not usable as indexes), so you'd have to build a balanced BST of m elements with counters at the leaves, and then do a counting sort with that instead of a simple array of m counters.

Comment: @harold I guess you are referring to [Binary tree sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree_sort) using a self-balancing binary search tree but I still don't see how you would get O(n log m) ?

Comment: @HischT what I had in mind was more like what jplot explained, only I explained it wrong. Oh well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can build an augmented balanced binary search tree on the `n` elements. The augmented info stored at each node would be it's frequency. You build this structure with `n` insertions into the tree, the time to do this would be `O(n lg m)`, since there would be only `m` nodes. Then you do a in-order traversal of this tree: visit the left subtree, then print the element stored at the root `f` times where `f` is it's frequency (this was the augmented info) and finally visit the right subtree. This traversal would take time `O(n + m)`. So, the running time of this simple procedure would be `O(n lg m + n + m) = O(n lg m)` since `m <= n`.